# Resharper 7.1, Mixed Versions of DevExpress in VS2012 Ultimate Crashes

Tags: c#, devexpress, resharper-7.1

After a recent purchase (Apr 2013) of Resharper 7.1, although the VS IDE did not crash,  The Visual Studio IDE Editor demonstrated strange behavior when refactoring code. My first instinct was to disable Reshaper refactoring since Visual Studio Ultimate has DevExpress installed and there might have been a conflict. From the Visual Studio IDE, I selected the Resharper\Options\ and a dialog displayed a message that Developer Express 7.1 was executing in Trial Mode. The dialog had "Trial Version" for a Serial Number.

I found this odd as I am running DevExpress 12.2.

I checked the Resharper installation directory and found DevExpress - 7.1 DLLs. I also noticed the DLLs had been altered in Jan 2013.

Apparently, the Resharper extension was distributed with DevExpress trial DLLs, I immediately uninstalled Resharper and a refund request in process.

Since uninstalling Resharper, the Visual Studio IDE crashes (with the typical message to generate a Microsoft Error Report). Visual Studio restarts.

I then uninstalled Visual Studio, DevExpress 12.2  (DX and CodeRush). 
The environment still crashes...

I am posting this with hope that another developer might have a solution or can recommend steps to help me diagnose these crash events.

Thanks!

Tim Peer

Comment: I copied the VS project to a neutral directory and recreate it after having reinstalled VS2012 Ultimate, DevExpress 12.2 and Coderush.

I attempted to recreate the sequence leading up to the crash and no problem.